# Reusing vs using new yeast

Tags: yeast, yeast-starters, reusing-yeast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many times can yeast be reused?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4352/how-many-times-can-yeast-be-reused)

I have read in a couple of places that you should only reuse yeast a couple of times - most say up to 5 times because you would get an infection eventually.

I now wonder if there is any indication for when to throw away the old yeast and get a new vial. I am obviously trying not to reuse until I get a batch that I need to throw away...

Would it be possible to detect this kind defect already in the starter maybe?

Comment: I prefer to buy fresh yeast most of the time, but look into "washing your yeast". Its a technique that uses a mild acid to remove any rogue bacteria from a yeast slurry without hurting the yeast themselves.

Comment: If that's not exactly what you're looking for, feel free to edit the question and I can open it back up again.

Comment: This one may answer some questions, as well:   http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/reusing-yeast-at-home